# Thinkpad X1 Carbon - volume buttons no longer working

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, thinkpad, volume-control

I've upgraded to 14.04 LTS, and now my volume up and down keys no longer work.

The mute button still works, bizarrely. The Media buttons (prev track, play/pause and next track) have also stopped working.

I have a previous generation Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon i.e. the one *without* the 'soft function keys', so this is not a softkey issue.

Worked previously with Ubuntu 13.10. I am using an up to date install.

uname output:
`Linux 3.13.0-34-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I've checked the system settings->keyboard->shortcuts->sound and media and they register the up and down volume keys just fine. If I change the keys to be (say) ctrl- and ctrl+, then I can alter the volume, but when I change them back to 'Audio lower volume' and 'Audio raise volume' by using the keys, they no longer change the colume or activate the top-right corner 'control flash' the same way that mute or brightness controls do.

I'm at a loss. There's obviously nothing wrong with the keys, but somewhere in the OS the keypresses are being diverted or dropped and they don't make it through to applications as events...

Comment: If you go into system settings -> keybaord -> Sound and Media, and click on the `Audio raise key` text, then press `Super` + `=`, does that shortcut work to raise it?